# Get the correct hour for a UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I think this is a stupid question, but seems that I cannot find the answer.

I have this timestamp: 1295598602.

In my php script I have:

> $date = date('Y-m-d', 1295598602);
>     $hour = date('H', 1295598602) . ':00';

This returns:

> Date: 2011-01-21
>   Hour: 03:00

Now I went to an online conversion site to test this. I used [this one](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm). 
But it seems that for this timestamp value it is

> Fri, 21 Jan 2011 08:30:02 GMT

Now, which one is correct?

Comment: It will depend on the time zone of your server, and the online service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use correct timezone:

```
>> date_default_timezone_get();
'UTC'
>> date('Y-m-d h:i:s',1295598602);
'2011-01-21 08:30:02'
>> date_default_timezone_set('CET');
true
>> date('Y-m-d h:i:s',1295598602);
'2011-01-21 09:30:02'
>> date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
true
>> date('Y-m-d h:i:s',1295598602);
'2011-01-21 08:30:02'
```

Answer (score 4):

In GMT / UTC (they're *almost* [but not quite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) exactly the same) that timestamp is indeed Fri, 21 Jan 2011 08:30:02 GMT.

If you're in a different timezone but always want GMT you'll need to use the `gmdate()` function instead of `date()`.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set() is only in PHP 5.1.0 and later, which may not be available.

Comment: Seriously? PHP 5.2 is now no longer supported by it's developers. If someone is still below 5.1, they should consider upgrading in the first place.

Comment: Seriously, yes.  I've seen a hosting company that still only has PHP 4.3.2 on its shared hosting web servers.

Comment: So what? I've seen people doing other stupid things. I always assume people work with current (or a least recent) technology. If they don't, they need to state that clearly, so that I can consider if I want to work with them at all, and at what price (because it surely won't be my usual rate).

Comment: My point was that if you specifically want GMT there's a perfectly good function which _always_ returns GMT, without faffing with changing the timezone, and which is in every version of PHP.

Comment: A valid point. I just tend to to use timezone setting, mostly because I work moore with DateTime objects. +1

Comment: This should be "H:i:s" as the small 'h' is not 24 hour clock.
02:00:00 and 14:00:00 both show as 02:00:00.
Doesn't affect the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. In the code snippet PHP adjusts for timezone. Try `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` to get proper unadjusted values.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set the default timezone for your script.

For example,

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$timestamp = '1295598602';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

would get you the same result as the online conversion tool is showing.

There are a number of timezone-related function in PHP that will allow you to modify which time zone is being shown.

You can check the PHP docs for a list of your options: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: `Europe/London` timezone respects daylight savings. Use `UTC` or `GMT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function description,

> timestamp is optional and defaults to
>   the value of time().

And according to [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function description, it returns GMT timestamp.

So, PHP does conversion to your time zone, while [onlineconversion.com](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) does not.