# checking a list of timestamps are between 12 and 1 in the day

Tags: php

I have a list of timestamps that represent a list of backed up files. But to reduce the amount of space needed I only want to keep the files that are from around mid day- I have started writing a function check but got stuck on how could i check if the timestamp is between 12 and 1 for that day? I have a list of timestamps for many days.

```
function check_date($timestamp='')
{
    if (($timestamp < strtotime("-1 week")) && (time is between 12 and 1 )){

    }    
    else
        remove 

}
```

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757078/get-the-correct-hour-for-a-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer to this previously, I will try find a link in a minute when im free but essentially get the timestamp for 12 and the timestamp for 1 then

```
if(timestamp12 < curTimestamp && curTimestamp < timeStamp1)
```

Then you know that the curTimeStamp is between 12 and 1.

Previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11578345/1475461

The other question was for a javascript implentation but timestamp comparison works the same whether you are using PHP, javascript etc. since they are miliseconds/seconds since a set point in time (1st January 1970), so it is just a comparison of integers.

Comment: No, I don't think this is quite what he wants. He wants to preserve all those, who got uploaded between 12:00 and 13:00 (1). That means, he has a different UNIX-Timestamp for every day he processes.

Comment: same principle for comparing the timestamps though surely?  It may not give him the answer to his question but it gives him an indication as to how to compare, which is the bit from his question he did not have any idea how to do.

Comment: Yes, I know. And didn't say 'wrong' either. But my answer uses that principle (of checking the timestamp). Only that I am running it through the 'localtime' function, which will tell him: 'This timestamp was at the date x at 12 hours and 53 minutes. This timestamp is between 12 and 13 at any day.'

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me think...ah, here it is. Good old 'localtime' function.
http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.localtime.php

Run your timestamp through this function, then you can check the result.

```
$TimeInfo = localtime(timestamp, true);
if (($timestamp < strtotime("-1 week")) && $TimeInfo["tm_hour"] == 12) {

}    
else remove
```

With this code, all files, which have arrived at 12:00, up to 12:59 (1 is excluded in this example) are preserved, the others get removed.